# Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given ERROR Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony

I was doing a simple update operation when this error occurred. The update operation is done but when I tried to get back to see the modification on the page I get this error below:

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

This is my Twig Code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ path('Update_comment',{'idc':comment.id}) }}">
    <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">New Comment <sup>*</sup></label>
         <div class="controls">
              <textarea name="contenu" cols="2" rows="20"></textarea>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
         <div class="controls">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class=" icon-pencil"></i>Edit
              </button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

This is my Action's code:

```
public function UpdateCommentAction($idc){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $cmt = $em->getRepository('MyAppUserBundle:PostComment')->find($idc);
    $idPost=$cmt->getIdPost();

    if ($cmt != null) {
        if (isset($_POST['contenu'])) {
            $cmt->setContenu($_POST['contenu']);

            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute("get_view_post", array('id' => $idPost));
}
```

---

and these are my routing's configuration:

```
get_view_post:
   path:     /blog/get/one/post/{id}/
   defaults: { _controller: "MyAppBlogBundle:Blog:getpost" }
Update_comment:
   path:     /blog/get/post/Comment/Update/View/{idc}
   defaults: { _controller: "MyAppBlogBundle:Blog:UpdateComment" }
```

I don't know where is the problem, especially that the Updation operation is working.

Comment: where is your preg_match code?

Comment: i'm sorry what do u mean by preg_match code?

Comment: yeah, you error is about preg_match, but I have seen it in your code.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: show to code that cause the error?

Comment: i have already posted my code :D

Comment: the `preg_match()` referred to in this issue is one performed by Symfony itself, meaning that it does not exist in the custom code, but is used to qualify the custom code within Symfony's scripts. Although OP didn't write the `preg_match()` query, they could provide the rest of the error code which will show the location of the file containing the query, as well as the line number within that file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run this from the command line in your Symfony project's root directory:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I suspect maybe you made changes and they are still cached.
Unless there's something else you haven't told us? I can't see where else that message comes from because you don't have `preg_match` anywhere.

Comment: i changed the path to somewhere else, and the error is gone